# Finding real and imaginary part of sum

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I need to find the real and imaginary part of the following sum:
$\sum_{k=0}^{8n-1} (1+i)^k$ and $(n\in\mathbb{N})$

Would be grateful for any kind of advice. I know I will need to differentiate the different cases, but when I write the sum for e.g. n=1 out, I don't see anything usable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sum of a geometric series $\dfrac{(1+i)^{8n}-1}{1+i-1}=\dfrac{16^n-1}i=i(1-16^n)$

Answer (score 1):

It is a sum of terms of a geomeyric sequence, the formula gives

$$\frac {(1+i)^{8n}-1}{1+i-1} =$$

$$-i ((1+i)^{8n}-1)$$

but

$$(1+i)^2=2i $$

You can take it now.